# Adding and updating Assets

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have a registry with an asset. I need to add a new asset, and then update the registry. The assets are an apportionment, where you send a value from one to the other one. If the receiving asset doesn't exist it's created with the new value assigned, and then the value it's taken from the sending one. When I have all the assets modified though the transaction .js and I want to update the registry, I do:

```
                if(exists==false){
                    return getAssetRegistry('org.basetis.bonusetis.apportionment')
                    .then(function (apportionmentRegistry) {
                        return apportionmentRegistry.addAll([apportionment1]);
                    })
                    .then(function () {
                        return getAssetRegistry('org.basetis.bonusetis.apportionment');
                    })
                    .then(function (apportionmentRegistry) {
                        return apportionmentRegistry.updateAll(apportionments);
                    })
```

which if I debug, goes through the addAll that adds the new created asset, but then, when it tries to update it with updateAll it gives me an error saying that the new added asset does not exist. If I delete the updateAll function, the new asset does get added. 
Why is it not able to update the asset if it has added it before in the code? Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: In Hyperledger Fabric (which Hyperledger Composer is currently using), you are not able to read your own writes from within a transaction, meaning that you cannot add something to a registry and then read it, in the same transaction. Also a minor point, from your code snippet, it looks  like apportionments is not defined

Comment: this is just part of the code, they are defined before. Thank you, I didn't know that, I will make a workaround by just updating the old ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Hyperledger Fabric (which Hyperledger Composer is currently using), you are not able to read your own writes from within a transaction, meaning that you cannot add something to a registry and then read it, in the same transaction.

Comment: Hi Paul, How to handle this scenario then ??

Comment: @Pradeep: two separate transactions

Answer (score 1):

Paul is right. And I think this has something to how a new asset is not really fully committed to the registry until the transaction is successful:

> Transaction processor functions will fail and roll back any changes
>   already made an error is thrown. The whole transaction fails, not just
>   the transaction processing, and anything changed by the transaction
>   processor function before the error occurred will be rolled back.

From: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/js_scripts.html